# How to redirect to a specific page of Vue-app via Flask

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flask, vue-router

I'm building an app that has a page which ends in '@' provides some meta info for the page without '@', for example if the page '/user/aabb' has info about the user 'aabb', then the page '/user/aabb@' is the meta page for that user.

The problem is, '/aabb' part doesn't really exist because the app is SPA. 'aabb' is simply delivered as a prop for the component used in '/user' routing. Nor I can directly access '/user/aabb@' in the same context.

So is there a way for Flask to render a specific page of a Vue-build app? so that if the user enters '/user/aabb' on the address bar it links into '/user' page with 'aabb' prop. If there is, I guess the following functionalities should be required.

1. Flask to redirect to a specific page inside of Vue-route.
2. Flask to send data to the vue-component of that page.
3. Vue to receive the data from Flask.

Or is there any other ways to solve this... issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to all your questions is to use [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/) with [HTML5 History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html).

As I mentioned in your last question, set up your Flask app to use the Vue SPA as the front-end

```py
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")
```

Then set up a router for your front-end URLs

```js
// router.js
import Router from "vue-router"
import Vue from "vue"

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  base: "/", // this should match the root path for your app
  mode: "history",
  routes: [{
    name: "UserMeta",
    path: "/user/:username@",
    component: () => import("./path/to/UserMeta.vue"),
    props: true
  }, {
    name: "User",
    path: "/user/:username",
    component: () => import("./path/to/User.vue"),
    props: true
  }]
})
```

You have to make the `@`-suffixed *meta* routes are listed before the normal pages in order to guarantee it doesn't think the username ends in `@`. See [Matching Priority](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#matching-priority).

In the example above, both components receive the `username` route parameter as a prop.

[image: Edit xenodochial-hertz-537oj]

You can then use one of the [Data Fetching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html) methods to load data into your components from your Flask API when your routes are loaded.

For example, using *Fetching After Navigation* and assuming you have a Flask app route for `/api/user/<username>`...

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="user">
      <!-- show user details here -->
    </div>
    <div v-else>Loading...</div>
  <//div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "User",
  props: { username: String },
  data: () => ({ user: null }),
  async created () {
    const res = await fetch(`/api/user/${encodeURIComponent(this.username)}`)
    this.user = await res.json()
  }
}
</script>
```